# Why does "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined" appear on Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Error Message:
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.

Sample Data:
Data

The error message appear after highlighted the sample data and clicked the "Button" that has an Assign script on it. Script is:

```
 function result(range) {
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][1].split(" ");    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == 1) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

(saw this code online and trying to make it work, but failed to)

Comment: How do you defined `range`?

Comment: Either `range`, `s`, or `range[0]` is undefined

Comment: @RudolfManusadzhian I am planning on setting the range depending on my how many rows I highlighted on the same column

Comment: @Aaron24 I was asking about code))

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the error indicates that you have an undefined array.

Looking at your code there are 2 places this could happen. Please check that the following are true:

- `range` is an array passed on to the function (the function cannot be called on its own, somewhere else you must have `result(arrayVar)` calling this function)
- `range` variable is an array that contains arrays, so it must be at the very least `[[]]` (for example `var range = [[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3]]`) would produce `range.lenght = 2` and `range[0].lenght = 3`, however if you have `[a1, a2, b1, b2]`, then `range.lenght = 4` and `range[0].lenght` will **not** work